# Ionic 2 view won't update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to build a simple custom module which will display errors across the app. I tried a number of things, however I can't get the view to update and show new errors. Here's the last thing I tried, just the relevant bits:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ErrorMessageComponent } from '../components/error-message/error-message';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ErrorMessageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ErrorMessageComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    ErrorMessageComponent,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**error.message.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'error-message',
  templateUrl: 'error-message.html'
})
export class ErrorMessageComponent {

  private error:string;
  private subscription: Subscription;
  private _error = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(
  ) {
    this.subscription = this.getError().subscribe(error => {
        console.log('getError', error);
        this.error = error;
    });
  }

  public getError(): Observable<any> {
      return this._error.asObservable();
    }

  public newError(error) {
    console.log('newError', error);
    this._error.next(error);
  }

  public dismiss() {
    this.error = null;
  }

}
```

**error-message.html**

```
<div padding *ngIf="error">
    <p class="error">
        {{ error }}
    </p>
    <button ion-button="bar-button" icon-only (click)="dismiss()">
        <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

I'm using this service on my homepage:

**home.ts**

```
import { ErrorMessageComponent } from '../../components/error-message/error-message';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public dataProvider: DataProvider,
    public errMsg: ErrorMessageComponent,
  ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.dataProvider.getJobs().then((resp:any) => {
        // dataProvider is rigged to throw an error, caught bellow
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this.errMsg.newError(e);
      }) 
    });
  }
}
```

In the console I can see both these logs: `console.log('newError', error);` and `console.log('getError', error);`. However, the view won't update. Probably it's me being an angular noob. Please help

Comment: You can try, create a provider to collect all error, this.errorProvider.error.push("errorMessage"); 
and show get all error message in error page where you want

Comment: Use a service instead of component :)

Comment: Thank you guys, a service/provider was what I needed.